# .NET MAUI - CollectionView of Carousels

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

**In .NET MAUI, I  would like to create a page which contains a CollectionView of Carousels. Below is an example image.**

[image]

---

The Itemsource of the collection view is a `List<RecipeGroup>` (*RecipeGroupCollection*). The `RecipeGroup` object contains the name of the group e.g *"Most Popular"* and a `List<Recipes>`. The Recipes object contains its name and image.

Essentially the collection view will be populated by carousels. The carousels will have a label from the recipe group and will be populated by `List<Recipes>`. I would then access the `Recipe` object to show the name and image.

Below is my XAML attempt:

```
<CollectionView 
ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeGroupCollection}"
SelectionMode="None">

<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:RecipeCollectionModel">
        <VerticalStackLayout>

            <Label Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
            <CarouselView ItemsSource="{Binding RecipeGroup}"
                                              PeekAreaInsets="100">
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:RecipeModel">
                        <Label Text="{Binding strMeal}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>

            </CarouselView>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

</CollectionView>
```

I am getting the following issue:

```
The property DataTemplateContent is set more than once
```

So my question is,

How do you nest a CarouselView inside a CollectionView?

Comment: Would you please provide the code in your  `ViewModel` or code-behind?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I will do that when I am free. My question is a carousel view or any other view with an item template possible to be nested? Because the datatemplate can't be set more than once. But essentially the viewmodel constructor contains lots of builders which builds a group model (name of carousel and list of recipes), this is added to a public list and is the basis of the item source for the collection view.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I suppose it can be achieved. You can try to remove `x:DataType="models:RecipeCollectionModel"` in the datatemplate  to see if it works. BTW, I see an example on nesting a CollectionView inside a CarouselView. You can take a look into [MauiComplexCarouseView](https://github.com/omegazero2310/MauiComplexCarouseView).

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks for your reply, I have seen that repository before, but i'm looking for the inverse (conceptually it should be the same).  With regards to this, `x:DataType="models:RecipeModel"`, I removed it and in Visual Studio, (inline) it showed the correct Binding data type of `RecipeModel` . However when using the property `strMeal`, the App does not compile and the  following error `Binding Property "strMeal" not found on "####.RecipeCollectionModel" . There is a mismatch between VS and compilation for the label binding property.

Comment: No worries,  please help create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link. I would be glad to see if we can figure it out.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I am currently quite busy ATM. For now I'm just using a grouped CollectionView. When I am available I'll see if I can upload a MRE and will let you know. Highly appreciate the time taken to look into this.

Comment: Look forward to hearing from you soon.